# Image with width and height exchanged with REST in Android

Tags: android, image, upload, height, width

I have 2 methods to paint an image from the gallery and rotate the image. They work fine.

My problem is that the image is uploaded to a server with REST. When the image is horizontal it is uploaded correctly. **But when the image is vertical, the width and height are exchanged, uploaded incorrectly**.

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you

**1. SHOW THE IMAGE**

```
Bitmap imagen = getImagenRotada();

private Bitmap getImagenRotada() {

    Bitmap mBitmap = decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath);

    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        int orientacion = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (orientacion == 6) {
            matrix.postRotate(90);
        }
        else if (orientacion == 3) {
            matrix.postRotate(180);
        }
        else if (orientacion == 8) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
        }
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        mBitmap = null;
    }

    return mBitmap;
}

private Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
    try {

        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);

        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = Utils.anchoPantalla(this);

        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight, scale = 1;

        while(true) {

            if(width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                break;
            }
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale++;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

**2. SEND THE IMAGE**

```
public String addPhoto() {

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(IPsBean.getIpFoodPhoto());

    try {   
        File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        FileBody bin = new FileBody(file);

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("photo", bin);

        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);  

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);  
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        String charset = EncodingManager.getContentCharSet(entity);

        if (charset == null) {
            charset = HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET;
        }

        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(instream, charset);
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        char[] tmp = new char[1024];
        int l;
        while ((l = reader.read(tmp)) != -1) {
            buffer.append(tmp, 0, l);
        }

        reader.close();
        instream.close();

        String received = buffer.toString();

        if (received != null && received.contains("OK")) {
            return "OK";
        } else {
            return "KO";
        }   
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    return "KO";
}
```

It is possible that the methods getImagenRotada or decodeFile are exchanging the width and height to rotate the image?

Comment: Sorry, but i do not understand your problem. When you display the image you scale and rotate it. When you send the image you send the file as is.

Comment: @greenapps When the image is vertical (more high that width) it is incorrectly uploaded. Its dimensions are not correct, exchanging the width and height

Comment: No. Impossible. That code just uploads a file. Does not change any byte of that file.

Comment: @greenapps Thats what I think, but if I do it from the app it upload bad but if the same file I upload it from the web, it upload ok.

Comment: What do you mean with 'upload it from the web'?

Comment: My app to upload photos to a website and there are shown. Then the images are uploaded from the app or from the web.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand anything of that. I already know that your app uploads images and i saw your code. So dont talk about your app when i ask 'what do you mean with upload from web'? The images are not uploaded twice is it?